# How to pass validated user input with in an input field of a webpage using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, input, while-loop

I want the user to type in her/his name then pass the user input to selenium so that it automatically types it in the search field for my website.
Is possible to first input, press enter then trigger selenium to forward the input to the browser. Why is it not working?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/acer/Desktop/chromedriver')
browser.get('website')

x = str(input('Your name: ')) #user inputs name here

if len(x) > 20: #the name van not be longer than 20 charachters
    Print(’shorter’)
    x # if longer than 20 input again

else: #if above is correct do following:
    def user():
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            try:
                browser.find_element_by_id('q').send_keys(x) #find input field with html id q and input the name
                browser.find_element_by_tag_name('button').click() #click next
    user()
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? I don't see an actual question here. What is the code involving checking the length of `x` meant to do? Why are you defining a function inside an else statement? Why even use a function here at all? Using a plain `except:` statement is a bad idea. I would strongly recommend learning more Python, and programming in general, before anything else. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides and tutorials.

Comment: Is there any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To demonstrate passing the user input to the input field when the user's name is not longer than 20 charachters, here is a small program which does the following:

- Opens the url https://www.google.com/
- Takes user input i.e.`name`
- Validates if the length of `name` is less then 5 characters.

  - if true, **`break`** the loop and pass the `name` to the *Google Home Page* search box.
  - if false, **`continue`** to ask for user input again.
- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, WebDriverException

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
  while True:
      name = str(input("Name please (max 5 charachters):"))
      if len(name) > 5:
          print("More than 5 charachters, please try again...")
          continue
      else:
          break
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys(name)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Name please (max 5 charachters):asdfgh
  More than 5 charachters, please try again...
  Name please (max 5 charachters):asdfghjkl
  More than 5 charachters, please try again...
  Name please (max 5 charachters):dev
  ```

---

### This usecase

You can follow similar logic for a 20 character long user input and your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
while True:
    name = str(input("Name please (max 20 charachters):"))
    if len(name) > 20:
        print("More than 20 charachters, please try again...")
        continue
    else:
        break
browser.find_element_by_id('q').send_keys(name) #find input field with html id q and input the name
```